# How to do a UserContext search in EF MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Looking for a low overhead way to check the `UserProfile` table of the simplememebershiprovider feature.

How can I look for MaxDebt less than 6 in the UserProfile table for the current user?

EF makes it heavy to return UserID, then do a UserID look up and check if the field, MaxDebt, is larger than 5.

What is the simplest way to return the row `MaxDebt` of the current user in EF/MVC4?

I only know the clumsy way atm.

```
        int userid = WebSecurity.GetUserId(model.RegistrationInfo.UserName);
        int debt;
        using (var ctx = new UsersContext())
        {
            debt = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT MaxDebt from dbo.UserProfiles where UserID={0}", userid);
        }
        if (debt > 5)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would make a model for the User appropriate for the UserProfile table. It would be something like:

```
[Table( "UserProfile" )]
internal class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int MaxDebt {get; set; }
}
```

Then do something like this:

```
using (var ctx = new UserProfileEntities())
{

     UserProfile user = ctx.UserProfiles.Find( userId );
     if( user != null )
     { 
         int debt = user.MaxDebt;
         ...
     }         
}
```

assuming UserProfileEntities is something like this:

```
class UserProfileEntities : DbContext
{
    static UserProfileEntities()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UserProfileEntities>( null );
    }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: So users is not an IQueryable, and does not have the attribute `MaxDebt`

Comment: Actually, since userId is the key we can just use .Find() - I have updated my answer.

Comment: The alternative is var testUsers = userProfileEntities.UserProfiles.Where( u => u.UserId == userId ) followed by checking:  if( testUsers.Any() ), then iterate through the users: foreach( var testUser in testUsers ). But Find() is easier as per my comment above and the updated code.

Comment: @czl Do the above comments answer your question? I use very similar code for my SimpleMembershiProvider table and it works fine, so it should work for you.

Comment: Yes after review, this is exactly the type of solution I was looking for.